# Problem training a model for housing dataset, ANN

Tags: python, keras

I am making a model to train on a housing datasets.  Below is the error I keep on getting:-

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'sklearn.preprocessing._data.MinMaxScaler'>, <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

The model is given below:-

```
 model=Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(7,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(7,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(7,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(7,activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy')

    model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=3,epochs=200,verbose=3,callbacks= 
    [early],validation_data=(X_test,y_test))
```

Comment: You should check whether your training data as well as the labels are all numpy arrays or not. It might be the case that it may contain an array as well as a list. Due to which you are getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your input data, i.e., training and testing data, are numpy arrays, instead of a lists. Don't forget to check the labels as well.